# How do I make the Pathfinder Trait 'Heirloom Weapon' function in PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment, pcgen

I'm working on a character for an upcoming campaign, and it's looking like I'll probably be taking the [Heirloom Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/equipment-traits/heirloom-weapon) trait.  I'm trying to get the character put together in PCGen, but I'm having some issues figuring out how to make the trait actually *function* within PCGen.

Here's what I've managed so far:

```
Heirloom Weapon     KEY:Heirloom Weapon ~ Trait     CATEGORY:Special Ability    
TYPE:Trait.EquipmentTrait       PREMULT:1,[PREABILITY:1,CATEGORY=Special Ability,Heirloom Weapon ~ Trait],[!PREABILITY:1,CATEGORY=Special Ability,TYPE.EquipmentTrait]  
DESC:You carry a non-masterwork simple or martial weapon that has been passed down from generation to generation in your family.
BENEFIT:When you select this trait, choose one of the following benefits:
    1) proficiency with that specific weapon,
    2) a +1 trait bonus on attacks of opportunity with that specific weapon,
    3) a +2 trait bonus on one kind of combat maneuver when using that specific weapon.
Note: You pay the standard gp cost for the weapon.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so I can pick the options, and have them actually effect the final character sheet properly.

Note: I'm planning on taking the proficiency option, so I'll settle for a trait for 'Heirloom Weapon (proficiency)' if things are too complex otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest stable version of PCGen (6.06.01) already has an implementation for Heirloom Weapon. You simply need to add the Adventurer's Armory (the source of the trait) to your Sources to make use of it. After you select Heirloom Weapon, another ability category is added to the Trait list, called Heirloom Weapon - you can select the specific benefit you want in here.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to code multiple versions of the same trait, so you would have:
Heirloom Weapon (Proficiency)
Heirloom Weapon (AoO)
Heirloom Weapon (Combat Maneuver)
and each would have only the benefit that you choose for that one.

As a disclaimer, I have had only minimum experience coding, so there may be a better workaround I'm not aware of.

Answer (score -3):

I would try to code Heirloom Weapon as something similar to an abstract class, so it MUST be inherited, with an abstract method to give the bonus, but no implementation, and then code all types of Heirloom Weapon bonuses as classes that inherit the abstract Heirloom Weapon and override the abstract bonus method, implementing the type of bonus that flavor of Heirloom Weapon is supposed to convey.